# linear gradient over an anchor link with image tag

Tags: css, background, anchor

I have this structure, where I want to apply a linear gradient to its image.

```
    <div class="link-img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/bild.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
```

So , I set the css so :

```
div.link-img{
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
 background: linear-gradient(
     rgba(0, 82, 144, 0.7), 
     rgba(0, 82, 144, 0.7)
   );
}

div.link-img img{
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

which is the only approach I could find. The problem with it, the link is disabled due to z-index: -1 applied to the img. Have you maybe a clue how to enable the link again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your anchor as a block element:

```
div.link-img > a{
    display: block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tm446jhL/1/)

Comment: @thegentletrainer Glad to have helped.